# Create a pandas Dataframe based on on a list of boolean conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
     Tkl  Def_Int   Sk                 College  Height (in)
0      NaN      NaN  NaN           Florida State        76.00
1      NaN      NaN  NaN                  Oregon        75.75
2     16.0      NaN  2.5                 Florida        74.63
3      NaN      NaN  NaN                 Alabama        72.88
4      NaN      NaN  NaN                    Iowa        76.63
...    ...      ...  ...                     ...          ...
5638   NaN      NaN  NaN            Georgia Tech        75.80
5639   NaN      NaN  NaN  Middle Tennessee State        72.00
5640   NaN      NaN  NaN               Minnesota        73.90
5641   NaN      NaN  NaN                Kentucky        73.50
5642   NaN      NaN  NaN           West Virginia        71.10
```

I'd like to create a new column based on a boolean condition of the 'College' column. If any of the colleges is in my list then power five is 'True', if not then the row would be 'False. I get a "Value Error: Lengths must match to compare" Here is my code below:

```
df['Power_five'] = df[df['College']==['Illinois',
'Indiana',
'Iowa',
'Maryland',
'Michigan',
'Michigan State',
'Minnesota',
'Nebraska',
'Northwestern',
'Ohio State',
'Penn State',
'Purdue',
'Rutgers',
'Wisconsin','Arkansas',
'LSU',
'Florida',
'Georgia', 
'Tennessee', 
'Auburn',
'Texas A&M',
'Kentucky', 
'Alabama', 
'Vanderbilt', 
'South Carolina', 
'Missouri', 
'Mississippi',
'Mississippi State','Kansas', 'Oklahoma','Texas', 
'Kansas State', 'Oklahoma State', 'Iowa State', 'Baylor', 'Texas Christian', 'Texas Tech', 
'West Virginia','Arizona',
'Arizona State', 
'Colorado',
'Oregon',
'Stanford',
'UCLA',
'USC',
'Washington',
'Washington State',
'Colorado State',
'Utah',
'Oregon State',
'Boston College',
'Clemson',
'Duke',
'Florida State',
'Georgia Tech',
'Louisville',
'Miami',
'North Carolina',
'NC State',
'Wake Forest',
'Syracuse',
'Pittsburgh',
'Virginia',
'Virginia Tech',
'Notre Dame'
                            ]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df['Power_five'] = df[df['College'].isin(the_list)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Power_five'] = df['College'].isin(['Illinois', 'Indiana', ...])
```